# a question about jump discontinuity and removable discontinuity

Tags: limits, continuity

The function $f(x)$ is given by the following:

$f(x)= ln\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) - 2x^2 + ln2$ if $0 < x <= 1$

$f(x)= \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right) \arcsin(a+2x)$       if $1 < x <= 3/2$

Does the function $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=1$ for $-3 < a <-2$

or

Does the function $f(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=1$ for $-3 < a <-2$ ?

I know that I have to check the equality of right-hand limit and left-hand limit for $x=1$ but
how can I check this if $a$ is a variable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand limit is $\ln (\frac  1 2)-2+\ln 2=-2$. The right hand limit is $\frac 4 {\pi} \arcsin (2+a)$. These two are equal iff $2+a=\sin (-\frac {\pi} 2)=-1$ iff $a=-3$.